# object with low vertex bend like having high vertex

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

this is a leg of a fox in mcprep add-on
it dont have many vertex as you can see. when i move one or some vertex, it didnt work like normal but act like this. i want to know how to make an object/model like this one then i can later make other things similar.
Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a subsurf modifier.

Comment: ah, thanks ! thats it. in wireframe view it have more edge.

Comment: Note that the pink edges have a "crease" value of 1. That means the geometry will try to get as close to the actual unsubdivided mesh as possible. To tweak the crease value, select at least 2 connected vertices and go to the right panel > Item > Transform and tweak the mean crease

Comment: @Gorgious wow, thank you so much ! I've learned a lot today.